# How to remove obsolete step functions that no longer exist in feature files in Cucumber JVM?

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am new to Cucumber JVM using Eclipse IDE. Normally after writing feature file using Gherkin, I use Junit Runner to run the feature file like below:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "Feature"
    ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
    )

public class CucumberTest {
}
```

Then I will get prompt from Eclipse saying "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below", and the missing step function definition is auto-generated:

```
@Given(xxxxx)
public void yyyy(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

I just copy and paste it to my step definition file and implement it. How convenient!

However sometimes i need to change my feature files often, and by doing so Eclipse will only ask me to add new or modified step definition, but it will not automatically clear the old step functions that are no longer needed by the feature file.

So is there a way to make the step definition consistent to the feature file by not manually changing it?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find Cucumber steps that are not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966367/how-to-find-cucumber-steps-that-are-not-used)