# Removing unused step definitions in Java-Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

We have 200+ features and 2000+ scenarios in our entire test suite. It works fine, but many step definitions are unused and we want to delete them.

Currently, it is very hard for us to manually try to remove step definition code and see whether doing so breaks anything. Is there a tool or utility that can identify which step definitions in a Java-Cucumber codebase are unused so they can be removed?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966367/how-to-find-cucumber-steps-that-are-not-used

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ's Cucumber plugin can search usages of individual step methods within the feature files. It is not really a bulk operation, but at least you can quickly see whether you can delete that step definition code, one by one, or not.

Comment: Available for eclipse ?

Comment: @BostonStar if not, then available for the Community edition of the Idea which you propbably could use.